# how to access ssh UserEnvironment var in pam_exec script

Tags: ssh, debian, pam

i am using the sshd_config variable PermitUserEnvironment

```
#/etc/ssh/sshd_config
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

to set something like "REALUSERNAME" on every key in the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file.

```
#/root/.ssh/authorized_keys 
environment="REALUSER=custom_value" ssh-rsa AAAAB3....
```

But i have trouble accessing the value in the script triggered by pam_exec in /etc/pam.d/sshd

my best guess is that the pam script is executed before the environment variables are set? So what are my options?

i tried pam_env

```
#/etc/security/pam_env.conf
PAM_REALUSER    DEFAULT="unkonwn" OVERRIDE=${REALUSER}
```

this is the custom part of my pam.d/ssh file

```
#/etc/pam.d/sshd
session    required     pam_env.so readenv=1
session    optional     pam_exec.so seteuid /usr/local/bin/scripts/my_script
```

even vars like SSH_CONNECTION seem not to be available which feels odd to me. The information must surely be avaible at the time of script executing but the variable is not set or i am doing it wrong.

i used to (successfully) trigger the script within /etc/profile so i am very confident that the issue is not within my custom script

Comment: Allowing the user to inject environment variables into the PAM environment would have security implications. I doubt the OpenSSH people would permit that without a compelling reason.

Comment: @Kenster as `PermitUserEnvironment yes` has security implications in itself i am not sure how this would be different. But then again i really have not enough knowledge to judge

Answer (score 0):

> But I have trouble accessing the value in the script triggered by `pam_exec` in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`
>
> my best guess is that the pam script is executed before the environment variables are set? So what are my options?

Yes, you are right. The environment variables from authorized keys are set up in [do_setup_env()](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/session.c#L1225) function, which is called after `pam_session`.

If you want to access these variables, I recommend you to set up `ForceCommand` or special shell for the user, which will be wrapper around normal shell, after you evaluate your variables.

But note that setting this for root, which is unlimited will allow your users to do whatever they want (even changing the keys, your environment variables), regardless your setup.

Comment: i was hoping i could omit using `ForceCommand`, thx for your answer

Comment: but what about the logout? surely by then all information are available, is there any way to reread the pam_env.conf later on?

Comment: what do you mean about logout? If you `exit` in the wrapper script, it will log the user out.

Comment: sry for being unclear. I was still talking about pam , specifically about `PAM_TYPE=close_session`

Comment: Why would you need that? `sshd` will take care of closing session, when the shell/command exits. And if you need to take some more actions in the during that time, you can do that still in the wrapper script.